# iOS Objective-C How to Select ALL using ELCImagePickerController

Tags: ios, image, uiimagepickercontroller

I am using Xcode 7 with ELCImagePickerController (Objective-C)

I have the library working great and I can select multiple images no problem...

The issue is, is there a way to select ALL images on the device? Some people have 1k+ images and I don't want to have to force them to click/select each individual image...

Thank you

Comment: You should open this as an issue on the ELCImagePickerController project website if this is a feature you want that currently doesn't exist. No one here can help.